# How can i convert a text file to JSON using PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have data in a text file like this:

```
data1
data1
data1
data1
data1
data1
data1
data1
data2
data2
data2
data2
data2
data2
data2
data2
data3
data3
data3
data3
data3
data3
data3
data3
```

The file can contain any numbers of lines, but the data is always in 8 line sections.
My desired output is valid JSON like this:

```
{
"data": [
    [
        "data1",
        "data1",
        "data1",
        "data1",
        "data1",
        "data1",
        "data1",
        "data1"
    ],
    [
        "data2",
        "data2",
        "data2",
        "data2",
        "data2",
        "data2",
        "data2",
        "data2"
    ],
    [
        "data3",
        "data3",
        "data3",
        "data3",
        "data3",
        "data3",
        "data3",
        "data3"
    ]
]
```

}

I have tried designing a php script to do this but i am hopeless with PHP, and i am nearly their, but can't get the formatting correct.

```
$tdcount = 1; $numtd = 8; // number of cells per row
$str = "{
    \"data\": [

     ";
$f = fopen("data.txt", "r");
if ( $f === FALSE ) {
    exit;
}

 while (!feof($f)) {
     $arrM = explode(",",fgets($f));
     $row = current ( $arrM );
     if ($tdcount == 1)
         $str .= "["; $str .= "\"$row\"";
     if ($tdcount == $numtd) {
         $str .= "]";
         $tdcount = 1;
     } else {
         $tdcount++;
     }
 }

 $str .= "] ] }";
 echo $str;
 exit;
?>
```

So i am wondering if theirs an easier way to do this and any example solutions that do what i require would be great.

Comment: What does your "data" really look like? I ask because here you are exploding by a comma yet the "data" you show appears to be separated only by line breaks, regarding *I have data in a text file like this*.

Comment: the data actually looks like this, for some reason the comma works for a new line

Comment: Actually the comma has nothing to do with a new line. Its the `fgets()` that is getting the whole line.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 main things - the first is don't try and build your own JSON, this quickly leads to issues.  Secondly is try and use some of the built in functions to make the coding easier (comments in code)...

```
$numtd = 8;

// read the file into an array
$data = file("data.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );

// use trim to remove any spaces
$data = array_map("trim", $data);

// array_chunk to split it into parts, output with json_encode
echo json_encode( ["data" => array_chunk($data, $numtd)], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```